# What's the best way to write a C#/MVC tool like SSIS to import address data from DB2 tables/files?

Tags: c#, import, db2, migration, data-cleaning

**Task:** to write an 'Area' in an existing c#/MVC webapp,
 where my users to choose their client's address data from **DB2** 'tables' 
 (actually, they're logical files in wrappers, don't ask, just think of them as files & fields) and clean it up for the new tables. The new address table has street names, building names, post boxes, postcodes, in their own columns. 
 My boss suggests using an intermediate/working table(s), and when the addresses are all pretty, put them in the new address tables.
**Source:** DB2 files with 3 or 4 fields of 25 or 30 char.  About 10% of the addresses are messy, with post-towns of 'Netherlands' or 'Norway', or county names, postcodes, or concatenated lines such as "Caterham, Reading".  Many (maybe 15%) are also duplicates.

**My Ideas so far:**
I'm thinking of a rule-based approach, which the user could select via a drag-and-drop, to give the input to my program classes, that would apply the chosen rules to a selected batch of addresses.  This would be repeated until they were all in the right form.  Also, another page in the UI so the user could over-type the crazy ones.

I do not want to re-invent the wheel if there is a tool already out there, or a design pattern I could use as a start point? 
I have tried googling, but possibly I used the wrong terms as I've found nothing like this scenario?

---

Some example rows of data:
File: DTALIBLE.ADRSFILE fields ADADR1, ADADR2, ADADR3, ADADR4 which should correspond to Building, Street1, Street2 and Town:

```
|  ADADR1       | ADADR2            |ADADR3              | ADADR4
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|               |6 HAPATISH STREET  |       PO BOX 2049  |  ZIONA                    
|               |LORTZINGSTRASSE 4A |       BIESENTHAL   |  GERMANY                  
|PINE GROVE     |SOUTHPORT          |       MERSEYSIDE   |  PR99AG
```

Our AS400 system has 6 or 8 long column names.  All the data is in upper case and is padded out with spaces as varchar wasn't around then.

To try and give context, here is a screen shot of another page in our mvc app so far; it gives an idea of the UI for this process that I need to end up with:
[image: Another page in our MVC app]

Comment: I am not understanding what you want.

Comment: A tool or design pattern? is there a best practise for this scenario?

Comment: I think it's just a lot of stuff together, you want to learn how to create an area, plus how to that correction on your database, but from what you are saying you want the user to be able to deal with this.

Comment: Can you show us some code or a sample of the data you want to deal with?

Comment: I'm cool with creating areas in c#/mvc, I was just trying to explain that this is where the eventual code must fit.

Comment: The data is in DB2 files, about 5 of them, so I was thinking of using dynamic sql on the source and EF to save them to the intermediate. Will add some example data rows to the question. Thanks so much for your interest

Comment: ok, but it's hard to picture it without actual data or code.